# For this method, how is regex working to catch the first letter in return str.replaceAll("(\\w)(\\w*)", "$2$1a?

Tags: java, regex-group

For the question and method below, how is this moving the first letter of each word, when both groups in the parenthesis are catching words? I understand that asterisk in regex means we are matching this pattern 0 or more times. I also understand that where is a swap in these two groups inside the parenthesis in “$2$1ay”. I just don’t see how the first letter is being captured.

Question:
Move the first letter of each word to the end of it, then add "ay" to the end of the word. Leave punctuation marks untouched.

Method used for answer:

```
public class PigLatin {
    public static String pigIt(String str) {
        return str.replaceAll("(\\w)(\\w*)", "$2$1ay");
    }
}
```

Comment: `\\w` doesn't "catch a word" (and neither does `(\\w)`), it only "matches a word character". The regular expression therefore matches "a word character" followed by "zero or more word characters"

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**

> How is regex working to catch the first letter in return str.replaceAll(“(\w)(\w*)”, "$2$1a? I just don’t see how the first letter is being captured.

`\w` matches **any single word character** and **not more than one word characters**. It is equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and **not** `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`.

**Explanation**

In your regex `(\w)(\w*)` (`"(\\w)(\\w*)"` as String in Java), `(\w)` is 1st capturing group (`$1`) which captures **a single word character**. `(\w*)` is 2nd capturing group (`$2`) which captures zero or more word characters. `$2$1ay` as replace string swaps both groups and appends `ay` just like you mentioned.

Check [this example](https://regex101.com/r/OtCDLq/2) on regex101.com for detailed understanding with color-coded visualization and for future references on regex.

Comment: This doesn't address my question about how the first letter is being captured if its part of the first word. That is what I am asking clarification on.

Comment: @RoyNunez, `\w` matches any **single** word character so `(\w)` capture first part (first character) of the word while `(w*)` captures remaining characters of the same word. If that is not your question, then please elaborate more as I am not able to get your question. Please refer https://regex101.com/r/OtCDLq/2 for color-coded visualization and detailed explanation.

Comment: This helps a whole lot. The word "word" had me confused, smh. Thank you!